# Time and date format change when import excel data to R

Tags: r, excel

I have an excel data which contains dates and times shown as 2019/8/24, and 09:00:00 and so on,  I am using

```
my_data <- read_excel("../data.xls")
```

to read it but I get $libxls error: Unable to open file$ error.

When I export .xls data to .xlsx and then import to R, I dates and times loose the format and appear in numerical format, 4370, 0.37 and so on.

Is the problem in the way I read the data or my data has problems?

Comment: You can try `read.xls` from the package `gdata`

Comment: Are you using RStudio?  If so, try the File / Import Dataset.